# pip3 install flask' returned a non-zero code: 1

Tags: python

1.This is the dockerfile

```
        FROM ubuntu:xenial
        ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
        RUN apt-get update
        RUN apt-get install python3-pip xvfb git software-properties-common -y
        RUN apt-get install software-properties-common -y &&\
            add-apt-repository ppa:thopiekar/pyside-git -y &&\
            apt-get remove software-properties-common -y
        RUN apt-get update
        RUN apt-get install python3-pyside2 -y
        RUN apt-get clean
        RUN pip3 install xvfbwrapper
        RUN pip3 install ghost.py --pre

        RUN pip3 install requests
        RUN pip3 install flask

        ADD . /code
        WORKDIR /code
        CMD ["/usr/bin/python3", "server.py"]
```

2.This is the docker-compose.yml

```
    version: '2'
    services:
      web:
        restart: always
        build: .
        ports:
        - "8000:8000"
        volumes:
        - .:/code
```

When i am running this command "sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d --build"

I am getting this error,

```
Step 12/15 : RUN pip3 install flask
 ---> Running in d911b7675dc2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 33, in vendored
    __import__(vendored_name, globals(), locals(), level=0)
ImportError: No module named 'pip._vendor.cachecontrol'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pip.exceptions import InstallationError, CommandError, PipError
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/exceptions.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.six import iteritems
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
    vendored("cachecontrol")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 36, in vendored
    __import__(modulename, globals(), locals(), level=0)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/wrapper.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/utils.py", line 25, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/certs.py", line 17, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/certifi/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .core import contents, where
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/certifi/core.py", line 85, in <module>
    Resource = Union[str, "os.PathLike"]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/typing.py", line 552, in __getitem__
    dict(self.__dict__), parameters, _root=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/typing.py", line 512, in __new__
    for t2 in all_params - {t1} if not isinstance(t2, TypeVar)):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/typing.py", line 512, in <genexpr>
    for t2 in all_params - {t1} if not isinstance(t2, TypeVar)):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/typing.py", line 190, in __subclasscheck__
    self._eval_type(globalns, localns)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/typing.py", line 177, in _eval_type
    eval(self.__forward_code__, globalns, localns),
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'PathLike'
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c pip3 install flask' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

What should I do to solve this error, please help me!
I dont know much about the docker and containers.
I am expecting to install flask succesfully

Comment: Ubuntu Xenial is over six years old at this point. Maybe this problem is caused by an old version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Did some more searching around. I believe you could do this pretty easily by changing the versions used to Ubuntu Focal and Pyside6 - do you need pyside2 specifically?